# Google Script Calendar Status Filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get my events from my calendar to a spreadsheet. I want to filter the guest statuses. But my code doesn't work at all. I get all events but I want to filter them actually...

```
var options = {'statusFilters[]': [ CalendarApp.GuestStatus.MAYBE , CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES ]};    
var calEvents = calendar.getEvents(startdate_sync, enddate_sync , options );
```

What is wrong here?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified script :

```
var calEvents = calendar.getEvents(startdate_sync, enddate_sync);
var filteredEvents = calEvents.filter(function(e){return e.getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.MAYBE || e.getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES});
```

#### Note :

- In my environment, `options` of `calendar.getEvents(startdate_sync, enddate_sync , options );` didn't work. So I would like to propose this.
- For your situation, please select one of following conditions.

  1. `e.getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.MAYBE || e.getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES`
  2. `e.getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.MAYBE && e.getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES`

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You understood it correctly and I have seen this solution before but: the problem is, I'm trying to create a team calendar which allows you to see all events of all team members. so I'm not sure, if getMyStatus() returns "my" status or the status of the person whom I want to see. I will try it.

Comment: and actually you can write a search term in these options. and it works correctly!! I think there is a mistake with my syntax although I don't get any error messages...

Comment: @Ezgi Tüter I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about your current script? If you can do, can you add it to your question?

Comment: I’m sorry but I can not add my script because I’ve wrote it for our company and I thing I’m not allowed to :/

Comment: @Ezgi Tüter I'm really sorry for the inconvenience.